# EF Core 2.2 - query is sent to database when using SelectMany and Include

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have a class `Asset` that has a list of children `Tag`:

```
public class Asset
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int AssetID { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int TagID { get; set; }

    public virtual Asset Asset { get; set; }
}
```

When I execute a query to retrieve all assets, along with their tags like so:

```
public class GetAssetsQuery
    {
        readonly IDataContext dataContext;

        public GetAssetsQuery(IDataContext dataContext)
        {
            this.dataContext = dataContext;
        }

        public async Task<List<Asset>> Execute(User user)
        {
            var allAssets = await dataContext.Assets
                .Include(x => x.Tags)
                .ToListAsync();

            return allAssets;
        }
    }
```

And I have another query to get all the tags using `SelectMany`:

```
public class GetTagsQuery
    {
        readonly GetAssetsQuery getAssetsQuery;

        public GetTagsQuery(GetAssetsQuery getAssetsQuery)
        {
            this.getAssetsQuery = getAssetsQuery;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Tag>> Execute(User user)
        {
            var allAssets = await getAssetsQuery.Execute(user);
            var tags = allAssets.SelectMany(x => x.Tags).ToList();
            return tags;
        }
    }
```

The query above then goes back to the database again for each asset to retrieve the tags. Shouldn't the `.Include()` have been sufficient in retrieving all the tags for the assets so it doesn't execute further queries?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo no they are not executed in the same scope, would that be a problem? I return `allAssets` to another class, which then creates the variable `tags` using `SelectMany`. I would've thought EF would be smart enough to realise it has already retrieved the required entities.

Comment: @Viqas it is. Only one query gets executed. `are not executed in the same scope` what does that mean?

Comment: My question should have been if both `allAssets` reference the same list. Thats the case as you explained, so no, shouldnt be an issue. On the moment that the assets list is created, the objects in it should already have the list of tags in it. Can you verify if this is the case? (Set a breakpoint and check the object references). A reproduction of your issue would be helpful.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo yep, tags are present for each of the assets in the `allAssets` variable. If I create the variable `tags` in the same scope, the query is not sent to the database, it's only when I try to create the variable `tags` in a separate scope that it goes to the database.

Comment: Can you please add the way that you are passing the source `allAssets` down the line?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo see my updated question.

Comment: IMO this should work as you expect. The objects contained in the list returned by `GetAssetsQuery.Execute` should have the eagerly loaded tags. Can you set up a minimal repro? You could use sqlite to map your context to a db file.